# ImageMagick ++ Read Error ErrorMissingDelegate

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I have downloaded and installed ImageMagick++ from http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/.

I am using Windows7 32 bit and Visual Studio 2008. I want to use the ImageMagick in an existing project. I made the required/suggested changes to my project properties like adding dependencies etc. I added three libraries in the additional dependencies (CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib,CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib and CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib

I added

1. `<Magick++.h>` header file and
2. `using namespace Magick`

Then

1. Magick:: Image image (No error)
2. image.read("5.png") throws an error "ErrorMissingDelegate at memorry location ....".

I tried other image formats also, but same error.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe try with `GIF` and `JPEG` images...

Comment: Hi Mark , Thanks but no luck. I tried with PNG,BMP, GIF, JPEG but same error on read. Please see if you can help me.

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick? There is a guide here... http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-windows-installation.php I think we may need to wait for Eric's (@emcconville) expertise to come online soon.

Comment: Hi,  I downloaded the binary from http://www.imagemagick.org. Even for the demo project (Button )which comes with this installation I am getting the same error, The link which you have sent allows to build from the source, but I am using the release and not building from the source.

Comment: I'm not around any windows machines, but I believe you want to link with the `.dll` libraries. If you go with the `.lib` route, then you'll also need to included all the `.lib` your expecting to use as [delegates](http://imagemagick.org/download/delegates/).

Comment: Hi. Do you mean that I shall have to download the required delegate project (say PNG) from the link provided by you? And then compile and generate a corresponding DLL and LIB file. And Include it in my project.

Comment: After installation I even converted some PNG images using command prompt. Then I opened Magic++_Demo.dsw and compiled it.
 It failed because the library name used was "CORE_RL_magic.lib" where as the actual library in the lib folder is "CORE_RL_Magic.lib".
I Changed the library names in the project properties and it compiled successfully.

But When I run it I get the following error on the line number 61 button.read( backGround)

Magick::ErrorMissingDelegate at memory location 0x0012fafc.

On the command prompt, I even checked the delegates and PNG is in the list.